# How do I optimize hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been trying to run my query but it always seem to be running like forever.
Would like to know how can I Improve on performance for this
Had to add in the group by Clause as the left join seem to be creating duplication when viewing the results.

Hierarchical Query Code

```
with NextValue (equip_id, link_id, node_fr_id, node_to_id ) as
(
    SELECT lm.equipment_id, l.link_id, l.node_fr_id_num, l.node_to_id_num
    FROM road_details l
    LEFT JOIN Equipment_details e ON l.link_id = e.link_id
    Where 1=1
    START WITH l.link_id = 2
    CONNECT By NOCYCLE Prior l.node_to_id_num = l.node_fr_id_num  
)
Select * from NextValue 

-- Select Particular Equipment starting with 'DET' --
Where 1=1 and equip_id like 'DET%'

-- Remove Duplicate cause by Join clause --
Group by  equip_id, link_id, node_fr_id, node_to_id;
```

Expected output:

| equip_id | link_id | node_fr_id | node_to_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DET_276627 | 990 | 1138 | 1141 |
| DET_546012 | 1881 | 4856 | 2322 |
| DET_546010 | 1980 | 2397 | 2437 |
| DET_526526 | 13176 | 14259 | 14260 |
| DET_526014 | 13724 | 14762 | 14763 |
| DET_536513 | 114721 | 114445 | 114446 |
| DET_526524 | 106130 | 105001 | 106402 |
| DET_516043 | 18803 | 19196 | 19198 |
| DET_526024 | 106319 | 106753 | 105919 |
| DET_526515 | 105796 | 105762 | 103751 |
| DET_526518 | 1061319 | 106514 | 104601 |
| DET_526037 | 99221 | 96871 | 94382 |
| DET_526510 | 99185 | 97133 | 97881 |

Current output:

| equip_id | link_id | node_fr_id | node_to_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DET_276627 | 990 | 1138 | 1141 |
| DET_546012 | 1881 | 4856 | 2322 |
| DET_546010 | 1980 | 2397 | 2437 |
| DET_526526 | 13176 | 14259 | 14260 |
| DET_526014 | 13724 | 14762 | 14763 |
| DET_536513 | 114721 | 114445 | 114446 |
| DET_526524 | 106130 | 105001 | 106402 |
| DET_516043 | 18803 | 19196 | 19198 |
| DET_526024 | 106319 | 106753 | 105919 |
| DET_526515 | 105796 | 105762 | 103751 |
| DET_526518 | 1061319 | 106514 | 104601 |
| DET_526518 | 1061319 | 106514 | 104601 |
| DET_526518 | 1061319 | 106514 | 104601 |
| DET_526518 | 1061319 | 106514 | 104601 |
| DET_526518 | 1061319 | 106514 | 104601 |
| DET_526518 | 1061319 | 106514 | 104601 |
| DET_526518 | 1061319 | 106514 | 104601 |
| DET_526037 | 99221 | 96871 | 94382 |
| DET_526510 | 99185 | 97133 | 97881 |
| DET_526510 | 99185 | 97133 | 97881 |
| DET_526510 | 99185 | 97133 | 97881 |
| DET_526510 | 99185 | 97133 | 97881 |

for odd reason it creating duplicates and hence had to add in the Group clause to counter this issue.. but with the group clause added in i've notice the longer querying duration occuring.

**Updates for commenters (not enough space to explain):**
Hi @HimanshuKandpal, let me just explain the query and what it is suppose to do. There are 2 tables, one is road_details and the other is an equipment_details. PK for the road detailsis Link_id, where equipment_id is the PK in the equipment_details and link_id is FK.

Brief explanation road details for context of what this hieratical query is aiming to do. Picture a map of inter connecting roads, e.g. a single road is made up of multiple links (Blocks) each block has a fr_id (head) and to_id (tail) ***[link_id 1 -> link_id 2 -> link_id 3]*** where `link_id1.to_id = link_id2.fr_id` as they are linked that way. The query is supposed to find out what is the next connecting link based on the criteria.

2nd criteria, with each link can have multiple equipment on it or non at all. If a user were to select a certain equipment type, as shown in my where clause are they able to know what is the next or previous link ID of a particular equipment with support from hieratical query.

Comment: HI , can you please send us the Explain plan for the query and the index details on the tables used in the query.

Comment: A quick guess as `LEFT JOIN` can lead to duplicates, have you tried `INNER JOIN` instead?

Comment: Hi @JeremyThompson yes I've actually tried using `INNER JOIN` to which is also creating duplicates and have left me quite perplexed as well.  If I do include the inner join within the CTE table of the Hierarchical query, I'll get returned an empty table due to the starting point of my root. Therefore only used it to join with the cte.

Comment: Did you try to do the connect by without the join, and join the result?

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal, updated my post with the explanation

Comment: @gsalem yes, I have still got duplicates, and I've tried different join conditions but oddly duplicates are still being created. Not going to include Distinct as this would greatly effect performance.

`With NextValue as 
(
    SELECT level, link_id, Direction, fr_id, to_id
    FROM road_details 
    START WITH link_id = 2
    CONNECT By NOCYCLE Prior to_id = fr_id
    ORDER Siblings BY to_id
)
Select e.equipment_id, nv.* From NextValue nv
INNER JOIN equipment_details e on nv.link_id = e.link_id and e.equipment_id like 'DET%';`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables; and the `INSERT` statements for the sample data that generates that output. Just having the output means we need to try to reverse engineer the input and the `WHERE equip_id like 'DET%'` condition has filtered out some of the rows so we cannot see your complete input making it difficult to reproduce. Please help us to help you by giving us everything to recreate the problem (and in a format we can just copy-paste and execute).

Comment: If you have a road network and you can go `A -> B -> C` or `A -> D -> C` then road `C` will appear twice as you can take two different routes to get to it. There is nothing odd about having multiple paths between vertices in graph theory.

Comment: My comment was to try to make the query run faster, not eliminate duplicates. Other comments try to address that point.

Comment: @MT0 now that you've mentioned it it does make sense. After closer look at the level iterations tagged to each duplicate, alright so that is some what solved. Allow me to prepare the sample data for the road linkages. its quite massive so i'll just take a sub section of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns you `SELECT` are all from the `road_details` table (assuming `lm.equipment_id` is a typo as there is no `lm` table alias and it should be `l.equipment_id`) and the `WHERE` filter is a column from the `road_details` table and the `START WITH` and `CONNECT BY` conditions are all using columns from the `road_details` table.

You `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the `Equipment_details` table which means that having matching rows is optional and you **NEVER** use any of its columns to either filter the input or generate the output so the `Equipment_details` table appears to be irrelevant to the output. At best, the SQL engine will optimise query and remove the join; at worst, there are multiple matching rows in the `Equipment_details` table for each row in the `road_details` table which will generate duplicates and then this number of duplicates will be exponentially magnified as the paths are followed deeper into the hierarchy.

For example, if you have the path without equipment:

- `A -> B -> C`

And compare it to having the same path with 2 equipment on each road:

- `A (with equipment A1) -> B (with equipment B1) -> C (with equipment C1)`
- `A (with equipment A1) -> B (with equipment B1) -> C (with equipment C2)`
- `A (with equipment A1) -> B (with equipment B2) -> C (with equipment C1)`
- `A (with equipment A1) -> B (with equipment B2) -> C (with equipment C2)`
- `A (with equipment A2) -> B (with equipment B1) -> C (with equipment C1)`
- `A (with equipment A2) -> B (with equipment B1) -> C (with equipment C2)`
- `A (with equipment A2) -> B (with equipment B2) -> C (with equipment C1)`
- `A (with equipment A2) -> B (with equipment B2) -> C (with equipment C2)`

The query will generate 8 duplicates that terminate a `C` (and it will get worse as the hierarchy deepens or if multiple paths reach the same junction).

You will still need to filter out duplicates as you can follow roads `A -> B -> C` and also `A -> D -> C` so `C` would be reached by two distinct paths without any duplication from equipment but including equipment will make the duplicates much, much more prevalent.

---

Since you never use the `Equipment_details` table, do not include it in the query and just use the `road_details` table:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       l.equipment_id,
       l.link_id,
       l.node_fr_id_num,
       l.node_to_id_num
FROM   road_details l
WHERE  l.equipment_id like 'DET%'
START WITH
       l.link_id = 2
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR l.node_to_id_num = l.node_fr_id_num
```

*(Note: using either `GROUP BY` with all the columns or `DISTINCT` will be doing the same job and performance should be similar for both and can be used interchangeably; you should profile each version and check. `DISTINCT` may be easier for future developers to comprehend what you are trying to achieve.)*

---

If the `equipment_id` column is in the `Equipment_details` table then you can generate the road hierarchy and then later join the equipment:

```sql
SELECT e.equipment_id,
       l.*
FROM   ( SELECT DISTINCT
                link_id,
                node_fr_id_num,
                node_to_id_num
         FROM   road_details
         START WITH
                link_id = 2
         CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                PRIOR node_to_id_num = node_fr_id_num
       ) l
       INNER JOIN Equipment_Details e
       ON (l.link_id = e.link_id)
WHERE  e.equipment_id like 'DET%'
```

or:

```sql
SELECT e.equipment_id,
       l.*
FROM   ( SELECT DISTINCT
                link_id,
                node_fr_id_num,
                node_to_id_num
         FROM   road_details
         START WITH
                link_id = 2
         CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                PRIOR node_to_id_num = node_fr_id_num
       ) l
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Equipment_Details e
       ON (   l.link_id = e.link_id
          AND e.equipment_id like 'DET%')
```

Comment: I started to answer something and you posted this. You seem to interpret that its original incorrectly aliased  `lm.equipment_id` is from the road_details table. In this case you perfectly nailed the issue and the jointure is unnecessary . But I had interpreted the other way around : its from the other table. Then the jointure make sense, even if the whole thing might be rewritten diffrently. OP should tackle this

Comment: @ThomasG The alias is certainly incorrect as there is no `lm` table identifier or alias. I assumed that the `m` was a typo and the alias was `l` (as that is the minimum change necessary to have a syntactically valid query). As you say, that assumption may be incorrect but if it is, and the alias is `e` (not `lm` or `l`), then the join should be an `INNER JOIN` as the `WHERE` filter would require that the `Equipment_details` row exists (but the SQL Engine will implicitly make that conversion so there should not be any change in performance). In that case, there is not much to improve.

Comment: lm is a typo... my bad. Thank you for the clearer explanation on how deepen hierarchy  makes things a little more complicated.